# Get price from table 1 if word is in the sentence tabel 2 (Excel, VBA, Vlookup, if, ? ,...)

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, vlookup

I try to get a price (col "B" sheet "PP") if a product (col "A" sheet "PP") is in any of sentence (col "A" sheet "MASTER"). If not, then it should pick up the average price (cell "C2" sheet "PP"). I've tried to use several methods but only this one gives SOME ;) results:

```
=IF((LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(B2);UPPER(LEFT(PP!A2;LEN(PP!A2)-5));"")))/LEN(LEFT(PP!A2;LEN(PP!A2)-5))>0;VLOOKUP(PP!A2;PP!$A$2:$J$82;2;0);PP!C2)
```

As you can see on a picture only a few products get results and it's not correct. I think it's because counting characters is different for different words and phrases. Maybe there are some other errors in this formula.

In Picture 1 you can see products with prices and its average from the sheet "PP".

[image: Picture 1. Sheet "PP" (Product Prices)]

In Picture 2 you can see sentences in which are products in red color - sheet "MASTER". There is one sentence - cell "B8", where are two products, and formula can pick up any of them, can be i.e the first one. Three last products on the mint background aren't in the list (sheet "PP"). Therefore for them, the formula should take an average price from cell "C2" sheet "PP".

[image: Picture 2. Sheet "MASTER"]

The formula should make a loop because the products from sheet "PP" can be in a few sentences.

Can anybody help me to solve this issue?

SOLVED:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15;SEARCH(PP!$A$2:$A$11;B2);PP!$B$2:$B$11);PP!$C$2)
```

Comment: Why are you checking lengths? You could simply use the `SEACH` function to see if a string in Sheet PP is contained within the string in MASTER and, if yes, perform the calculation. Or, perhaps, I'm missing something... Am I?

Comment: You're absolutely right! It works! Here is a formula:
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15;SEARCH(PP!$A$2:$A$11;B2);PP!$B$2:$B$11);PP!$C$2)

Comment: Glad my input helped. Cheers!!